# How to get an active window title between two browser tabs/windows using Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, java

I can switch between two tabs/windows but my requirement is to know or get active window between them.

In my project, on a click of a webElement of a page a random pop(tab/window) gets opened and I would like to know whether that(new) window has focus or my original page.

I tried to use JNA Api to get the active window and its title but my web page is
remotely located.

I would like know the active window title of a browser or system which is remotely located(need this for all platforms and browsers)

Perfect solution is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code you used for that?

Comment: you can find out which is active window by URL also   driver.getCurrentUrl();

Answer (score 2):

If you perform a simple `getCurrentUrl()` before you click, then after that event do another `getCurrentUrl()`, if the values match, then your original window has focus.

pseudo code (assuming you want the focus Not to be the popup);

```
string pageBeforeClick = driver.getCurrentUrl();
click(YourPageElement);
string pageAfterClick = driver.getCurrentUrl();
assertEquals(pageBeforeClick, pageAfterClick, "Your active window is the popup");
```

Obviously you can wrap the last line in an `if-else` statement if that's what you require.